# Unable to delete a repository with sudo ppa-purge

Tags: repository, 22.04

When I try to update the system via sudo apt update I get the following error message:

```
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Does anyone know how to delete this repository which is not needed in my case, I tried sudo ppa-purge but it didn't work?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: what does "didn't work" mean? did you get an error message, or something else? What command did you use, exactly?

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file

Comment: Unfortunately not, I've already tried to delete it with ppa-purge but then I get the error: sudo: ppa-purge: command not found

Comment: "Command not found" in this context means ppa-purge isn't installed.

Comment: I just installed ppa-purge and now when I try [sudo ppa-purge https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release] I get the following error: E: The repository 'https:// ppa.launchpadcontent.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/system76/pop/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
Warning: apt-get update failed for some reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ apt-add-repository --help
...
Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -m, --massive-debug   Print a lot of debug information to the command line
  -r, --remove          remove repository from sources.list.d directory
...
```

*In 20.04; but I expect it to be the same...*

Comment: I've already tried that but always get the following error message: sudo: ppa-purge: command not found

Comment: but thanks for the willingness to help

Comment: The command is `sudo apt-add-repository -r ...`.

Comment: when I use sudo apt-add-repository I get the following back after running the command:
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/system76/pop/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.

Comment: @BennetWeber that's because you need to use `ppa:micahflee/ppa` or whatever, not the whole link. like `sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:micahflee/ppa`

Comment: @BennetWeber with ppa-purge you do `sudo ppa-purge <link>` (NO `jammy` or `Release` needed)

Comment: @Esther As you can see, I'm a newbie to Linux and Unix in general, thanks a lot!